# 8192 limited data size in NodeJS request

Tags: node.js, requestjs, nodejs-stream

I'm trying to fetch json from an api but only half of the response is received. So how to get the full response?

```js
var request = require('request');
var url_to_check = 'http://example.com/api/test';

request.get(url_to_check).on('data', function(data) {

// Only half of the data is printed (8192). Remaining bytes are lost.

    console.log(data.toString());

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct the only mistake you made is that you are streaming request data so you won't get whole data on event 'data' if a response is large. You will have to collect chunk and consolidate on event 'end'. check this code snippet

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
var req = request.get(url)
var data = []
 req.on('data',function(chunk){
   data.push(chunk))
 })
 req.on('end',function(){
   console.log(Buffer.concat(data).toString())
 })
```

And If you don't want to stream and pipe data and also response size is small then you can try this:

```
    request.get(url, function(err, response, responseBody) {
    if (!err) {
        // var jsonRes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))
        // responseBody = jsonRes.body
        console.log(responseBody)
    } else {
        // handle error here
    }
})
```